# generate jwt when signing in with allauth

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-allauth

How would you generate a token with [django-rest-framework-jwt](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt) and pass it to a template that can store the token in localstorage, when signing in with allauth?

I know django-rest-framework-jwt lets you generate tokens via POST:

```
$ curl -X POST -d "username=admin&password=abc123" http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/
```

But how would you implement this in the login/signup flow of allauth?

Comment: Will you use allauth login/signup as rest framework endpoints for login or signup?

Answer (score 5):

(I have not used JWT but I don't believe there is anything special about JWT compared to regular tokens, other than the extra security and more importantly, not having to keep a database table of tokens. So, my answer is for regular tokens, assuming/hoping you can adjust to JWT)

I am assuming you are trying to write stand-alone client, in which case, the problem is that django-allauth is not really intended for use with cleints/APIs, so a lot of the magic cannot be used through an API. See this some how old issue, which I believe is still valid: [3rd party REST/JSON APIs](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/360).

If you scroll to the end, you will see somebody recommending the use of [django-rest-auth](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth) to handle the social login for the API, while keeping the main django-allauth handing the native django web site side of things.

I have not yet used them both together (I am currently not supporting social login on the API side, so haven't had to deal with it).

[This post](https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial) shows an excellent example for developing an Angular Client using django-rest-framework. You will see how it creates its own APIs to registering and logging in. You should be able to replace that part with django-rest-auth, but the point is that django-allauth won't really play a big role on anything that comes via the API (unfortunately).

Finally, you may also want to check my own implementation [here](https://github.com/dkarchmer/aws-eb-docker-django). Look at the 'authentication' app, and look at the tests for how is used, which is my version of link [3](https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial)

Answer (score 3):

`allauth` is basically for multi page Apps, for API login i recommend relying on
`rest_auth` [Rest Auth Docs](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

It has built in Login/Register etc built on top of `all-auth` but for Single page apps.

then update settings, to

```
REST_USE_JWT = True

'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
            'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
            'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',

    ],
```

Now You should receive jwt token in response to login calls.